# How do i parse the results of a SPARQL query in Marklogic?

Tags: sparql, xquery, marklogic

i run a SPARQL query in Marklogic, and it gives me the results i want, here is a part of the results:
[image]

How can I loop through this data so the results are like this:

```
Analityker: Analyst
```

?

I tried converting to json, but then all I get are arrays and I can't get to the data itself individually

for example:

```
let $prel_result := sem:sparql($sparql_string)
let $conv_result := xdmp:to-json($prel_result)
```

then the type of `$conv_results` is "array"

If I do this:

```
let $original := $conv_result//english
```

Then I get again an array of all the first column:

```
[
  "Social Skills und Methoden", 
  "Analytiker", 
  "Entscheidungsbaum", 
  "Use-cases"
]
```

I tried lopping through the data, but I can't seem to figure out to get it to work. I can't seem to loop through it.
I tried tokenizing the results, but it tells me it is not a string.

I want to output more or less like the screen copy above, without the headers. Basically one line per word and it's translation.

Comment: ok, i seem to be on my way to a solution using something like this :

for $i in (1 to 4)
return $original[$i]

how can i get the value for the 4, i won't always know how many lines of results i have?

Comment: Try fn:count($original)

Comment: thanks, it seems to work... i had tried it originally, on my other variable, $conv_result and it wasn't working, only gave me 1 value because that vairable is an array, but with $original, it seems to work, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yep - fn:count() only works on Sequence not array-node . So you could use it on $prel_result or $original in your example.